# recognize bash variable inside a text file

Tags: bash

I have a file template that will be used by a shell script to generate other files and just change a fill information inside this file template using variables.

content of file `template.example.log`:

```
server name: $HOSTNAME
current user: $USER
```

I try different ways to do this works.

content of file `log.sh`:

1) do not work, the output file `some_log_1.log` is the same as `template.example.log` and the variables was not changed.

```
FILE_TEMPLATE="`cat template.example.log`"
cat > some_log_1.log <<EOF
$FILE_TEMPLATE
EOF
```

2) do not work with echo command too, happen the same as above.

```
echo $FILE_TEMPLATE > some_log_1.log
```

but if I do this, it works!

```
cat > some_log_1.log <<EOF
    server name: $HOSTNAME
    current user: $USER
EOF
```

the output is right!

```
server name: ubuntu-server
current user: leafar
```

but I do not want the script run in this way.
I want to read the content of a text file and cat it into another text file and `fill the variables`.

HOW CAN I DO THAT?
THANKS. 
Ps: sorry about my weak english

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to use `sed` to edit the files. This lets you limit what variables get filled in.

This will fill in template.txt and output it to filled.txt:

```
sed -e "s/\$HOSTNAME/$HOSTNAME/" -e "s/\$USER/$USER/" template.txt > filled.txt
```

template.txt:

```
server name: $HOSTNAME
current user: $USER
```

filled.txt:

```
server name: ubuntu-server
current user: leafar
```

Comment: this work, but the hostname variable is empty, did u have any idea why?